# How to extract kernel headers for compiling kernel module later

Tags: linux-kernel

I compiled various Linux kernel from git repositories. There are times when I copied the kernel to other system and need the kernel header to compile external module.

I tried to run "make headers_install" but it only generated a include/ folder. When I tried to point external module to that folder, it complains it cannot find Makefile.

What is the proper way to package kernel-header for deployment?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `There are times when I copied the kernel to other system and need the kernel header to compile external module.` ? Copy the kernel root directory over to another system ? If yes, then you just need to figure out how to build modules by providing the path to the built kernel.

Comment: @VivekS I don't want to copy the entire kernel root directory to another system, because it's a git tree, so it's huge. I only want to copy a snapshot of the kernel source. Even than, I don't want to use git archive because for building kernel modules, I don't need .c files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create kernel packages instead, that's "make deb-pkg" for dpkg based distros and "make rpm-pkg" for RPM based ones. These create multiple packages, one of those is a package usable for external modules building. That should be linux-headers-* for the Debian packages and a "devel" package for he RPM versions.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I'm looking for. It will be perfect if it only generates header files, because my kernel image is huge (~500MB), so it takes a while to generate kernel image which is not used. Though, if nothing else, this is a workable solution!

Comment: I just found there is also a binrpm-pkg target which at least should not build source packages (unless the devel package counts as a source package, I don't know). The Makefile and scripts are in scripts/package. I don't know a lot about RPM building, but if you do, you may be able to patch the rpm call in the Makefile to build just the package you need.

Comment: On Debian, there's the `make-kpkg` program in `kernel-package` package; I find that the easiest way to build kernel images and headers for installation.

Comment: @TobySpeight `make-kpkg` was relevant a long time ago. Then the `make deb-pkg` target in upstream did everything while not being as unreliable as `make-kpkg` was (which often broke with the latest kernels IIRC). There appear to still be users, but I don't see the need for it.

Answer (score 1):

In some ways this is just an expansion of [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19497460/213180).  If you look at the file scripts/package/builddeb in the kernel sources you will find script code which selects the files needed for building external modules from a kernel build and puts them into /usr/src/linux-headers-$version.  I can find that script code in my local kernel version by searching for the string "# Build kernel header package" in the builddeb file.  If you want to do things by hand you could execute that script code manually.