# Is there a minimal set of files to keep from a Linux kernel compile for compiling kernel modules later, as needed?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

After I compile a linux kernel, I need to keep the huge souce directory in my disk for the further external module's compiling.

I can not simply run **make clean**,  because this fails me when I compile some modules in this way:

```
$ make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build
```

I roughly read the Makefile of kernel source, but there seems not a target to do this work.

Question:

**What files are valuable that I should copy from the working linux source directory for the further use of compiling external module?**

Comment: Everything in your distro's `kernel-devel` package or its equivalent thereof.

Comment: I known this kind of package provided the necessary files. (pacman -S linux-headers in my archlinux system will install the system provided kernel's source files) . Obviously not work for my own kernel.  :)

Comment: Those are still the files you need to keep in order to build modules regardless.

Comment: It seems the version of kernel matters. I get the list of files of linux-headers package and then test the existance of files in my working linux source directory. I find a lot of the listed files missing. Maybe It was not the best method to just copy the listed files out of my dirty directory.

Comment: The common solution is to get a bigger disk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract kernel headers for compiling kernel module later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486335/how-to-extract-kernel-headers-for-compiling-kernel-module-later)

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to figure it out by trying to build an external module against clean kernel source. You can notice next errors:

> ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
>
> `include/generated/autoconf.h` or `include/config/auto.conf` are missing.
>
> Run `make oldconfig && make prepare` on kernel src to fix it.

and

> WARNING: Symbol version dump `./Module.symvers`
>
> is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.

To make sure that all needed files are in place do next:

1. Save `Module.symvers` and `.config` files from your kernel build.
2. Now you can clean your kernel:

   ```
    $ make distclean
   ```
3. Copy stored `.config` file back to your kernel source directory and do next:

   ```
    $ make modules_prepare
   ```

   This fixes first error.
4. Copy stored `Module.symvers` file back to your kernel source directory. This fixes second error.

---

This is it. You are all set to build external modules with minimal set of built files in your kernel sources.

You also don't actually need all kernel source files to build external module. You can only leave next files:

```
.
├── arch
│   └── x86/*
├── include/*
├── scripts/*
├── Makefile
└── Module.symvers
```

Comment: Thx, I will test this soon later. I am reading the Archlinux's package script of linux-headers. That one generate the necessary directory structure include all needed files for external modules' compiling.